# Conflicting configuration settings with IsNullable = true IsNullable = false reusing ComplexType

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I do not know if this behavior is by design or it is a bug in EF6, or there is another way to do this. Having this complex type:

```
[ComplexType]
public partial class Company    
    public bool HasValue { get { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Name); } }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

I reuse it in these two entities:

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public Customer ()
    {
        this.Company = new Company();       
    }

    [Key]
    public int IdCustomer { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public virtual AcademicInfo AcademicInfo { get; set; }
}


public partial class AcademicInfo
{       
    public AcademicInfo()
    {
        this.Organization = new Company();
    }       

    [Key, ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public int IdCustomer { get; set; }

    public Company Organization { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Degree { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

in the dbcontext's OnModelCreating (EDIT: I added FK code I omitted before for simplicity):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{    
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

    // ... Other code here related to entities not related to the problem reported omitted to avoid confusion.

    modelBuilder.Entity<AcademicInfo>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.Customer)
            .WithOptional(c => c.AcademicInfo)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .Property(p => p.Company.Name)
            .HasColumnName("CompanyName")
            .IsOptional(); // CONFLICT HERE
    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .Property(p => p.Company.EmailAddress)
            .HasColumnName("CompanyEmailAddress")
            .IsOptional();  //CONFLICT HERE
    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .Property(p => p.Company.PhoneNumber)
            .HasColumnName("CompanyPhoneNumber")
            .IsOptional();

    modelBuilder.Entity<AcademicInfo>()
            .Property(a => a.Organization.Name)
            .HasColumnName("OrganizationName")
            .IsRequired(); // CONFLICT
    modelBuilder.Entity<AcademicInfo>()
            .Property(a => a.Organization.EmailAddress)
            .HasColumnName("OrganizationEmail")
            .IsRequired(); // CONFLICT
    modelBuilder.Entity<AcademicInfo>()
            .Property(a => a.Organization.PhoneNumber)
            .HasColumnName("OrganizationPhone")
            .IsOptional();
}
```

The Add-Migration command fails with the following error: 
**Conflicting configuration settings were specified for property 'Name' on type 'Company': 
    IsNullable = False conflicts with IsNullable = True**

But it has no sense because I defined the fields not nullable in AcademicInfo table and nullable in the Customer table.

Comment: HasColumnName() defines the column the property will target in your database. You are trying to define different names and nullable rules for the same columns. By default, the FK should be nullable, so you need to use HasOne() and WithOne() methods for non-nullable

Comment: @james, they are not the same colums since in the database the nullable columns are defined in the Customer table and the non nullable ones are in the AcademicInfo table. There is no FK involved in the problem so I removed the code related to it: 

    modelBuilder.Entity<AcademicInfo>()
    .HasRequired(a => a.Customer)
    .WithOptional(c => c.AcademicInfo)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but still valid for EF version 6.1.3.

According to [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/35) the behavior is an Entity Framework limitation about how to configure a particular complex type.

> This is a limitation of EF, some property facets need to be stored in C-Space and EF doesn't have a way of configuring a particular usage of a complex type. So you can only specify different S-Space facets like ColumnName or ColumnType